# Symfony2: How to install the dev-master version of Doctrine to resolve "Erroneous data format for unserializing" with composer?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, composer-php

I'm trying to fix Doctrine's **Erroneous data format for unserializing** bug as referenced **[here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-3120)** and **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24031048/fos-userbundle-unable-to-login)**.

---

My `composer.json` looks like this ...

```
require: {
    "symfony/symfony": "~2.5",  
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2", 
    "doctrine/orm": "dev-master",
    "...": "..."
}
```

... but composer complains that it can't find a matching package:

> doctrine/orm dev-master requires doctrine/dbal >=2.5-dev,<2.6-dev ->
>   no matching package found.

How can I resolve the dependencies **without** forking or raising the `minimum-stability` in the `composer.json`?

UPDATE:
Nifr's suggestion worked, this is the new config:

```
"symfony/symfony": "~2.5",
"doctrine/orm": "dev-master",
"doctrine/dbal": "@dev",
"doctrine/common": "@dev",
"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "@dev",
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can *"whitelist"* packages that currently have a lower stability level than the *"global"* `minimum-stability` defined in your composer.json by using **[stability flags](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#package-links)**.

In order to stop composer from complaining ...

> doctrine/orm dev-master requires doctrine/dbal >=2.5-dev,<2.6-dev ->
>   **no matching package found**.

... just require the doctrine/dbal package explicitly with the `@dev` stability flag.

Therefore execute ...

```
composer require doctrine/dbal:@dev
```

... or add the entry to your composer.json manually:

```
require: {
   "...": "...",
   "doctrine/orm": "dev-master",
   "doctrine/dbal": "@dev"
}
```

Repeat this procedure for all dependencies that don't match the global `minimum-stability` until composer installs without complaining.

---

**Further reading:**

Igor W. has published an excellent [blog article](https://igor.io/2013/02/07/composer-stability-flags.html) explaining stability flags in detail.